# Remove Toolbar and Footer from @mui/x-data-grid while export pdf

Tags: material-ui, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

I have created data grid using @mui/x-data-grid.
Below is my code snippet,

```
                <DataGrid
                    {...data}
                    autoHeight
                    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
                    pageSize={pageSize}
                    onPageSizeChange={(_size) => setPageSize(_size)}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 30]}
                    checkboxSelection
                    selectionModel={selectionModel}
                    disableSelectionOnClick
                    onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => {
                        setSelectionModel(newSelectionModel);
                    }}
                />
```

I have found below link for the hide toolbar and footer from grid while export PDF

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#print-export

I have tried below code but it is not working correctly.

```
<GridToolbarExport
  printOptions={{
    hideFooter: true,
    hideToolbar: true,
  }}
/>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to implemetnt that code into my above code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
type GridToolbarCustomProps = {
 id: number
}

const GridToolbar = ({ id }: GridToolbarCustomProps) => {
 <GridToolbarExport
  printOptions={{
    hideFooter: true,
    hideToolbar: true,
  }}
 />
}

<DataGrid
 {...data}
 autoHeight
 slotsProps={{ toolbar: { id: 1 } }} //grid toolbar Custom Props
 slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
 components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }} //Deprecated
 pageSize={pageSize}
 onPageSizeChange={(_size) => setPageSize(_size)}
 rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 30]}
 checkboxSelection
 selectionModel={selectionModel}
 disableSelectionOnClick
 onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => {
  setSelectionModel(newSelectionModel);
 }}`enter code here`
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).